# Create a list of random integers and then put all numbers that are the same right beside eachother

Tags: python, for-loop, random

```
def run():
    lst=[]
    for i in range(0,20):
        ran = random.randint(1,10)
        lst.append(ran)
return lst
```

So far I have created a list of random integers from 1 to 9 with 20 values, however how can I incorporate a swapping method so that values that are the same but not next to eachother will be next to eachother?

Thanks

Comment: Why not sorting the list?

Comment: All other values must stay in their order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random

#this is the function you gave with little edits, to see the changes it make
# after the process

def run():
    lst=[]
    for i in range(0,20):
        ran = random.randint(1,10)
        lst.append(ran)
    print(lst)
    swap(lst)
    print(lst)
    return lst

#this uses indexes of every element, and checks every other element of the list.
#this swap function works for lists with element made up of strings as well.

def swap(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        nu_m=lst[i]
        x=i+1
        while x<len(lst):
            dump=i+1
            acc=lst[i+1]
            if(lst[i]==lst[x]):
                lst[dump]=lst[x]
                lst[x]=acc
            x=x+1
x=run()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can build your own sorting criteria using indexes for the `key` argument.

```
import random

def run():
    lst=[]
    for i in range(0,20):
        ran = random.randint(1,10)
        lst.append(ran)
    return lst

lst = run()
print(lst) 
#[5, 10, 5, 1, 8, 10, 10, 6, 4, 9, 3, 9, 6, 9, 2, 9, 9, 1, 7, 8]
result = sorted(lst, key = lambda x: lst.index(x))
print(result)
#[5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 1, 1, 8, 8, 6, 6, 4, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 3, 2, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps just sort the list:

`lst = sorted(lst)`

Answer (score 0):

First let's create another list to keep the order of the unique numbers (like a `set`, but not sorted).

```
unsorted_set = []
for nb in lst:
    if nb not in unsorted_set:
        unsorted_set.append(nb)
```

Now that we got this list, let's create a final list that will continue that list but each number will be repeated n times, n is the occurences of the number in the first list. We will do this with `lst.count()`

```
final_list = []
for nb in unsorted_set: 
    for _ in range(lst.count(nb)):
        final_list.append(nb)
```

> Note that this code can be simplified a lot with *List Comprehension*.

Comment: any clue on how to put parenthesis around the values that are repeated in a print statement?

Comment: ex. 1 2 5 (4 4 4) 3 2 (6 6) 2 (1 1)

Comment: Do a `for n in unsorted_set` and `print("({})".format(' '.join([n for _ in range(lst.count(n))])), end=' ')`